# Is "I'm of several minds about it" valid English?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idioms

I've heard this in a TV show (Westworld), but I couldn't find anything about this phrase specifically, in Google. What does it mean exactly? Is this a common/acceptable way to say it?

Comment: Hello, Nicofisi. Have you looked up "of several minds" on the internet? I'd say "in several minds {about something) is the more normal metaphor, but you can check on Google Ngrams.

Answer (score 1):

'I'm in two minds about it' is a common expression indicating that you are hesitating between two courses of action. When I googled it I found entries for 'of two minds' as well (maybe an American version?). Presumably the TV character was adapting the expression because there were several options open to them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links to articles using **of several minds**:

> Being o*f several minds*: Voices and versions of the self in early
> childhood. [PsycNET](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1991-97339-008)
>
> POLL FINDS AMERICANS *OF SEVERAL MINDS* ON HEALTH [NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/1986/05/22/us/poll-finds-americans-of-several-minds-on-health.html)

Meaning different thoughts, typically more than two. IMHO, it is acceptable usage.

Answer (score 0):

*To be of several minds* in probably an older expression that hasn't died out everywhere. It is probably a plural analogy with *of a mind*

> I was ever *of a mind* that God did keep a plague for them of Paris in store...**Calendar of State Papers.. of the reign of Elizabeth(1)**[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=cEjWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22of%20a%20mind%22&dq=%22of%20a%20mind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbmMaa8_XaAhWCvFMKHZo3DbUQ6AEILTAB)

[John Wesley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wesley) used the plural

> It is an unavoidable consequence of the present weakness and shortness of human understanding, that several men will *be of several minds* in religion....[**Sermons on Several Occasions, volume 1**](https://books.google.com/books?id=qIwwAQAAMAAJ&q=%22of%20several%20minds%22&dq=%22of%20several%20minds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN1f209fXaAhXHyVMKHTV6DpEQ6AEIVDAI)

This idiom may be lost in the UK today, but is still in use in North America. I sometimes say "I'm of more than one mind" about something, or, "of several minds" .